# Why is viewcontroller property not being set?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In a method fired by a button I call this code:

```
//Get the sVC in order to se its property userLocation

    UITabBarController *myTBC = (UITabBarController*)self.parentViewController;
    for(UIViewController *anyVC in myTBC.viewControllers) {
        if([anyVC.class isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
        self.sVC = (SecondViewController *)anyVC;
        [self.sVC setUserLocation:self.userLocation];

        NSLog(@"userLocation ISSET to %@ from %@", self.userLocation, sVC.userLocation);
    }
```

The console log always logs the correct `self.userLocation` value, but not the `sVC.userLocation`, which always comes up null.

This method is in one of the tab-uiviewcontrollers of a uitabbarcontroller whereas the SecondViewController is the other tab-uiviewcontroller.

Why is `sVC.userLocation` not being set?

Comment: in sVC how is the property set for userLocation?

Comment: In sVC it is set by the property synthesizer. I dont set it explicitly in sVC, only in fVC.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if([anyVC.class isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
```

should probably be:

```
if([anyVC isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
```

because you want to know if *`anyVC`* (not `anyVC.class`) is of type `SecondViewController`.

The value returned by `anyVC.class` (or `[anyVC class]`) will be of type [`Class`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-objc_class) and will never be of type `SecondViewController` (so the `if` condition always returns `NO`).

Since the `if` condition is never satisfied, `self.sVC` never gets set and probably stays `nil` meaning the `setUserLocation` call does nothing, etc.

Also, you probably want to put all the statements related to `self.sVC` inside the `if` block otherwise the `setUserLocation` and the `NSLog` get executed even if the `if` condition fails:

```
for (UIViewController *anyVC in myTBC.viewControllers) 
{
    if ([anyVC isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
    {
        self.sVC = (SecondViewController *)anyVC;
        [self.sVC setUserLocation:self.userLocation];
        NSLog(@"userLocation ISSET to %@ from %@", ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other things you might need to take into consideration:

- Have your alloc/init your userLocation variable in sVc such as in `-init` or `-viewDidLoad`?
- Do you have a `@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *userLocation` in sVc class?

Comment: Nope, Its not being set. I thought it was, but its not. I dont think i should init it in vDL because the tableVC is not initted until the user taps on its tab in the tabbarcontroller. So if i set it in the mapVC and then switch over to the tableVC (which inits it), it erases the set value.  Even though the code for setting it is still not working. I still get null for sVC.userLocation in the NSLog